# Написание программы в С

Tags: c, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

Программа для вычисления длин сторон прямоугольного треугольника и его площади (вычисление длины должно быть оформлено в виде функции).

Вот собственно мои не особо успешные труды:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void sidelength(int numb1, int numb2, int numb3, int numb4, int i)
{
    float len[3] = { 0 };
    float length = sqrt(pow((numb2 - numb1), 2) + pow((numb4 - numb3), 2));//довжина сторони
    len[i] = length;
    printf("\nlength %f", length);
    printf("\nlength %f", len[i]);
    if (i == 2)
    {
        float p = (len[0] + len[1] + len[2]) / 2;//error(півпериметр)
        float square = sqrt(fabs(p * (p - len[0]) * (p - len[1]) * (p - len[2])));//error(площа прямокутного трикутника)
        printf("\n! %f", p);
        printf("\n! %f", square);
        printf("\nlength %f %f %f", len[0], len[1], len[2]);
    }

}

void main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int x1;
        int x2;
        int y1;
        int y2;
        printf("Enter x1:");
        scanf("%d", &x1);
        printf("Enter x2:");
        scanf("%d", &x2);
        printf("Enter y1:");
        scanf("%d", &y1);
        printf("Enter y2:");
        scanf("%d", &y2);
        sidelength(x1, x2, y1, y2, i);
        printf("\n");

    }
    
}
```

Проблема с массивом `len[i]` - он сохраняет только последнее значение.
Буду благодарен тому кто сможет предоставить исправленный код

Comment: Как выглядит ваш треугольник? Просто по двум точкам можно построить бесконечное их количество...

Comment: он никак не выглядит мне просто надо чтобы user вводил поочерёдно по две точки,с которых программа выводит длинну стороны,потом с этих размеров вычесляем полупериметр,и далее с того что имеем по формуле Герона площадь(если всё ещё не ясно перефразируй свой вопрос ибо я новенький тут и в кодинге)

Comment: А если я введу (1,1)-(2,2), (3,3)-(4,4), (5,5)-(6,6) - словом, три совершенно не пересекающихся отрезка? Далее, вы говорите о прямоугольном треугольнике, но  это же никак не проверяется...

Comment: И еще - пусть это и не относится к программированию, но еще Дейкстра говорил, что нельзя стать программистом, будучи безграмотным. Простите, но такое количество ошибок просто удручает. Оправдываться тем, что вы с Украины, не стоит - я тоже оттуда :) Не учат русскому языку - ну так учитесь сами, для украинца это очень просто... И вдогонку - формула Герона пригодна не только для прямоугольного треугольника.

Comment: извините за каламбур,на старте у меня есть три точки,вершины прям триугольника,это я смогу исравить задав их константами,тем не менее мне нужно решить проблему с len[i] ибо как я понял цикл заполняет одну ячейку масива и удаляется тоесть условно i=0 [1][0][0] i=1 [0][1][0] i=2 [0][0][1]

Comment: а причем тут прямоугольность треугольника вообще? формула Герона позволяет найти площадь любого треугольника зная  длины его сторон, я бы вообще убрал свойство "прямоугольности "из задания и текста, оно только путает, а для прямоугольного треугольника площадь это половина произведения катетов, тут и формул никаких не надо, этож половина площади прямоугольника

Comment: понимаете,я получу три длинны сторон(два катета и гипотенузу),следовательно чтобы подогнать код под формулу через катеты мне ещё нужно вычеслить какая из линий гипотенуза,а как по мне куда быстрее всё организовать через формулу герона для трёх сторон

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так - с заданием не 6, а только 3 точек - вершин треугольника.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double length(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    x1 -= x2;
    y1 -= y2;
    return sqrt(x1*x1+y1*y1);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double x[3], y[3], l[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        printf("X Y of point %d : ", i+1);
        scanf("%lf %lf",&x[i],&y[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        l[i] = length(x[i],y[i],x[(i+1)%3],y[(i+1)%3]);
        printf("Length of edge %d: %lf\n", i+1,l[i]);
    }

    double p = (l[0] + l[1] + l[2])/2;

    double S = p*(p-l[0])*(p-l[1])*(p-l[2]);

    if (S < 0) printf("Non-exist triangle\n");
    else printf("Area of triangle = %lf\n", sqrt(S));

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

полагаю что проблема в том что массив len[] нужно сделать более глобальным, да и ввод точек сделать лучше контролируемым, координат всего 6 достаточно а не как у Вас 12

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
float len[] = { 0, 0, 0 };
void sidelength(int numb1, int numb2, int numb3, int numb4, int i)
{
    
    float length = sqrt(pow((numb2 - numb1), 2) + pow((numb4 - numb3), 2));//довжина сторони
    len[i] = length;
    printf("\nlength %f", length);
    printf("\nlength %f", len[i]);
    if (i == 2)
    {
        float p = (len[0] + len[1] + len[2]) / 2;//error(півпериметр)
        float square = sqrt(fabs(p * (p - len[0]) * (p - len[1]) * (p - len[2])));//error(площа прямокутного трикутника)
        printf("\n! %f", p);
        printf("\n! %f", square);
        printf("\nlength %f %f %f", len[0], len[1], len[2]);
    }

}

void main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int x1;
        int x2;
        int y1;
        int y2;
        printf("Enter x1:");
        scanf("%d", &x1);
        printf("Enter x2:");
        scanf("%d", &x2);
        printf("Enter y1:");
        scanf("%d", &y1);
        printf("Enter y2:");
        scanf("%d", &y2);
        sidelength(x1, x2, y1, y2, i);
        printf("\n");

    }
    
}
```

Пример [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/BEyPXR)

И если немного упростить...

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float sidelength(int numbx[], int numby[], int n, int n1)
{
    return sqrt(pow((numbx[n1] - numbx[n]), 2) + pow((numby[n1] - numby[n]), 2));//довжина сторони
}   

void main()
{
    float len[3], p, square;
    int x[3], y[3];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter node x%d:", i);
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
        printf("\nEnter node y%d:", i);
        scanf("%d", &y[i]);
        if(i > 0)
            len[i] = sidelength(x, y, i, i - 1);
    }
    len[0] = sidelength(x, y, 2, 0);
    p = (len[0] + len[1] + len[2]) / 2;//(півпериметр)
    square = sqrt(fabs(p * (p - len[0]) * (p - len[1]) * (p - len[2])));//(площа будь-якого трикутника)
    printf("\nSquare: %f", square);
    printf("\nLength: %f %f %f", len[0], len[1], len[2]);
}
```

Пример тут [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/0uaXSw)

Comment: спасибо вам большое,я новичок в прогаммировании,не знал некоторых моментов,теперь знаю